# wxPython - RichTextCtrl Event Handling

Tags: python, wxpython, richtextctrl

For testing purposes, I'm trying to print in the console everything that I write in a RichTextCtrl. However, it isn't working. Here is the way I wrote the binding for the RichTextCtrl, called textArea:

```
self.textArea.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.syntaxColoring_C )
```

And here is the event handler:

```
def syntaxColoring_C( self, event ):
    print self.textArea.GetValue()
```

However, when I type something, only a blank line is printed in the console, and nothing appears written in the RichTextCtrl. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by chaning the first given line to `self.textArea.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.syntaxColoring_C, self.textArea )`, although I'm not sure it is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be corrected by adding `event.Skip()` in your event handling.

```
def syntaxColoring_C(self,event):
    print self.textArea.GetValue()
    event.Skip()
```

Quoting from [This link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/),

> You’ll notice that I also call “event.Skip” at the end. Iif you don’t call Skip, then the key will “eaten” and there won’t be a corresponding char event. This won’t matter on a button, but you might care in a text control as char events are the proper way of catching upper and lower case, accents, umlauts and the like.